# asp Validation Is not Working On Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, server

Why is ASP.NET validation not working on server?

This is my validation in aspx page..

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
     class="form-control" ControlToValidate="txttitle" ErrorMessage="*" 
     ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="lmn"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>`

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="fileupldimg">Image</label>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="fileupldimg" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Button:

```
<asp:Button ID="bannerbtn" runat="server"  Text="Submit" 
     OnClick="bannerbtn_Click" ValidationGroup="lmn"/>
```

This validation is working on localhost but when using server we get an error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Could not find a part of the path'G:*********\IMG'
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'G:*********\IMG\'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Comment: This is **ASP.NET** - not the VBA-driven "ASP classic" - changed the tag

Comment: still not working in server...any suggestion please

Comment: Where in your application is the reference to g:\.....\img? Don't see that in your code examples.

Comment: Why it's affecting the validation I don't know, but the exception refers to not finding a path starting G:. I would start by having  a look at what you have mapped locally as G:, and making sure that the server can access it as well. I would be interested to find out why a path affects the validation

Comment: g\*****\img is on the server..and my image path is ("~\\IMG\\" + fileupldimg.FileName)

Answer (score 0):

changes validation in html(html validation) : required="required"
`<asp:TextBox ID="txttitle" runat="server" required="required" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>`
and in button:

type="submit"